# How to add auto line break and maximum column width to table

Tags: php, html, html-table, width

How can I add different maximum width to my table columns? I'd also like to have an auto line break when I write something into the columns. Here's my code:

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Kategorie</th> <th>Titel</th> <th>Betroffene Seiten</th> <th>Beschreibung</th><th>prioritaet</th><th>Status</th><th>Eingereicht von</th><th>Umsetzung mit Release</th><th>Dev. Kommentar</th><th>Entwickler</th><th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>" ;
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['kategorie'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['titel'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['betroffen'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['beschreibung'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['prioritaet'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['eingereicht'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['umsetzung'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['kommentar'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['entwickler'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">bearbeiten</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">löschen</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the syntax of this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a width to your td in pixels or %. setting in one td will set it for the column.

```
echo '<td style="width:40px">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
```

I didn't understood you intenstion by:

> "when I write something into the columns."

you can use the `\n` to get new lines in your php code. just add it to your code where appropriate.

[you can see here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?186207-New-line-in-php)

you can also use `<br />` in your HTML to get the same line break.

Comment: Thanks, column width worked fine! There's an edit function in my script, where a user can edit the content of the table. When The user writes a long text there should be an auto line break and table width should stay in width

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following to break line in column and keep max width,

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Kategorie</th> <th>Titel</th> <th>Betroffene Seiten</th> <th>Beschreibung</th><th>prioritaet</th><th>Status</th><th>Eingereicht von</th><th>Umsetzung mit Release</th><th>Dev. Kommentar</th><th>Entwickler</th><th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>" ;
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['id'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['kategorie'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['titel'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['betroffen'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['beschreibung'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['prioritaet'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['status'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['eingereicht'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['umsetzung'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['kommentar'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="'.strlen($row['id'])+5.'">' . wordwrap($row['entwickler'], 20, "<br />\n") . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">bearbeiten</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">löschen</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

using **strlen** function set max width to td and using **wordwrap** break column value to new line